# Change Y position on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, position

I am trying to make it so that when you hover the mother or the sliding_child, the position of the sliding_child moves to the bottom half of the sliding_child. Notice that the height is twice as long as the mother.

HTML

```
<div class="mother">
    <div class="sliding_child">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in risus accumsan, elementum ipsum id, molestie lorem. Suspendisse eu eros vitae ipsum consequat vehicula quis fermentum tortor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.mother {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

div.sliding_child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: simple like this http://jsfiddle.net/BBHV7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
div.mother {
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
border:1px solid black;
position : absolute;
overflow : hidden;
}

div.sliding_child {
width: 200px;
height: 600px;
position : relative;

}
div.sliding_child p{
height : 300px;
margin : 0px !important;
}
div.sliding_child p:first-child {
background : blue;
}
div.sliding_child p:nth-child(2) {
background : yellow;
}
div.sliding_child:hover {
```

top:-300px;
   }

Comment: Doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: I think some of my other code in the elements in colliding with it, I'll try, gimme a sec

Comment: YES! It works. But the wrong way, I need the child moving up instead of down, to show the content on the second 300px of the 600px.

Comment: Nothing appears different from the last link..??

Comment: If you want to show the two element initially use this link otherwise use the previous.
http://jsfiddle.net/BBHV7/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative` on both the parent and the child and `top: -100%` on the child when hovered. Also consider setting the children position and dimensions in `%`, so that this works whatever the size of the parent is.

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .25rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    top: 0;
    transition: all linear .25s;
}

.child:hover {
    top :-100%;
}

.firstHalf,
.secondHalf {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.firstHalf {
    background: red;
}

.secondHalf {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="firstHalf">Hi</div>
        <div class="secondHalf">There!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer using `:hover` on the parent instead of the children:

```
.parent:hover > .child {
    top: -100%;
}
```